# Django: show raw html (from database) as html, not rendered

Tags: django, django-templates

I have created a rich text area using tinymce. I have now saved this to my database and want to display it. It gets saved in the database as html with tags, etc. To display it I have tried:

In views:

```
content = get_content_from_db()
render_to_response("template.html", {"content":content})
```

In template:

```
{{content}}
```

This shows the content with the tags like so:

```
<strong>My text</strong>
```

instead of just displaying the text as bold.

I have also tried using the verbatim tag, but this (doh!) displays as:

```
{{content}}
```

How should I do this? Do I need to save it differently? I save it the way I save any other TextArea except the field is a blob.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

```
{{ content|safe }}
```